# Permanently fixate the Gizmo to my mesh

Tags: mesh, transforms, axis, gizmo

Good Morning.

How do I permanently attach the Gizmo to my mesh, so that as I rotate my mesh the Gizmo rotates with it?

Whenever I add a new mesh, it's easy to rescale and readjust on every axis, but after a rotation it's tough moving the mesh from Point A to B: I have to move along the X and Y axis till I get to my destination.

But If I can permanently attach the Gizmo to the mesh, wherever the mesh rotates to, my Gizmo rotates with it making adjustments easier.[image]

Comment: When you do `G` `X` it moves on the global x-axis. but you can also move it along its local axes by using `G` `X` `X`. just double xx or yy or zz. you can see it in the upper left corner a text saying global/local-x replacing the `Object Mode` combobox. try pressing G you will see Global by default. Then tap X again then you see Local.

Comment: Yes, @HarryMckenzie. This is what I am looking for. Thank you very much. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to lock the movement to a certain axis, see the comment by @HarryMcKenzie under your question.

If you want to have the *Move* gizmo permanently visible, go to the *Viewport Gizmos* menu on the top right of the *3D Viewport*, enable *Object Gizmos* > *Move* (you can also choose if it should be the *Default* or a *Global*, *Local* etc. gizmo).

You can either enable this everytime you need it or save this setting in your startup file. To do that, after opening Blender or a new "General" project, go to the top menu *File* > *Defaults* > *Save Startup File*.

[image]

Comment: Yes. Thank you.